# django sending file to another server using threads

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

"I am sending file to another server using request.post . For reducing the time i am using the daemon thread. I am not doing any operation on the file but still getting
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
"

```
class UploadDocument(APIView):
    permission_classes = ([DeviceDocumentLimitAuth])
    def post(self, request):
        
        try:
            notebookId=request.data.get('notebookId')
            file= request.FILES['file']
            notebook = get_single_notebook_sercive(notebookId)
            file_name = request.data.get('file').name
            upload_file = request.FILES.getlist('file')
            upload_file_link=upload_file[0]
            daemon = Thread(target=uploadDocument_service, daemon=True, name='Monitor',args=(file, notebookId, file_name, upload_file_link))
            daemon.start()
            
            
            return success(message="successfully uploaded the document", response_data={'data': "ingestion in progress"})
        except Exception as err:
            return error(message=str(err))
```

```
def uploadDocument_service(file,notebookId,file_name,upload_file_link):
    
    source_response = requests.post(create_source_api,
                                    data={
                                        'notebook_id':notebookId,
                                        'source_type': 'PDF'
                                    },
                                    files={'file': file})
    
    print('made the request',source_response.status_code,source_response.json())

    if source_response:
        result = source_response.json()['result']
        source = result['source']
        sourceId = source['source_id']
        document = create_document_model(
            file_name=file_name,upload_file_link=upload_file_link,notebookId=notebookId, sourceId=sourceId)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.